Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'caseId' of type 'Id'
Hello the recordId is not populated
this is my code
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
  public static CaseWrapper handleCase(Id caseId) {
    String caseIdStr = String.valueOf(caseId); // Convert Id to String

    System.debug('caseIDcaseIDcaseIDcaseID'+caseIdStr);
    try {
      Case caseRecord = [
        SELECT
          Id,
          ContactId,
          L1_AdresseEmailContact__c,
          CaseNumber,
          marque__c,
          L1_NomAssurePrincipal__r.AdresseEmailFlex__c,
          L1_NomAssurePrincipal__r.PersonEmail,
          L1_NomAssurePrincipal__r.L1_PA_Email_professionnelle__c,
          L1_NomAssurePrincipal__c
        FROM Case
        WHERE Id = :caseId
        LIMIT 1
      ];

JavaScript
  @api recordId;

  getCaseId() {
    console.log('Record ID:', this.recordId);

    handleCase({ caseId :  "$recordId"})
      .then((caseResult) => {
  

        this.destinaire = caseResult.destinataire;
        this.demande = caseResult.caseRecord.CaseNumber;
        this.marque = caseResult.caseRecord.marque__c;
        this.currentCase = caseResult.caseRecord;

        if (this.marque) {
          this._folderValue = this.marque;
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error extracting Case ID from URL:", error);
      });
  }


the result "Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'caseId' of type 'Id'"

can someone help me

This is because you are trying to use the reactive variable of "$recordId" in your LWC by using Imperative Apex call. You can only use "$recordId" if you are using (@wire), Lightning Wire Service.
In your case you should make your Apex to have cacheable = true
and in your JavaScript
@wire(handleCase, {caseId: "$recordId"})
caseRecord({ data, error }) {
  if(data) {
      //logic
  }
  if(error){
      //logic
  }
}

You can read more about this here (highly recommended). Code credits also belong to this same documentation.
